# PHP user session menu

Tags: php, mysql, session, menu

Ok, so I've searched the site here alot, but to no avail, I did not find a solution, my code it to have when a user is logged in to display the login menu, when they are not logged in to display the logged out menu:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!$_SESSION['myusername'])
    {
    echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a> | <a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="torrent.php">Search</a>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Welcome <b>'; echo $_SESSION["myusername"]; echo'</b> | <a href="torrent.php">Search</a> | <a href="addtorrent.php">Add a Torrent</a> | <a href="logout.php">LogOut</a>';
    }
    ?>
```

But when they are logged out it says:
Notice: Undefined index: myusername

What can I do to fix this? I've done many things.

Comment: Use `isset($_SESSION['myusername])`.

Comment: Sadly, it does not work

Comment: Beware of the typo in my comment - it is `$_SESSION['myusername']`, notice the closing quote I missed before.

Comment: I saw it, still does not work.

Comment: The site is live at http://207.190.124.134/

Comment: It logs in, and then shows the links non-logged in users should not see.

Comment: It just means that it's not defined, so you get a notice.  You can change PHP settings to that notices aren't displayed, you can prepend it with `@` (I believe, didn't check for that type of statement, might not work with it, but that is the suppression operator.)  But basically, check if it is `isset` before attempting to use it.

Comment: @Jon: IMHO it's a very bad idea to teach beginners to work around warnings by suppressing errors.

Comment: Jon, I would like to have just the ONE error to go away not all of them by turning error reporting off

Comment: True, but it's a notice which is useful to know how to deal with, however any properly set up production machine is going to suppress them anyways.

Comment: IDK what I am going to do, I may just find some premade code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
    {
    echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a> | <a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="torrent.php">Search</a>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Welcome <b>'; echo $_SESSION["myusername"]; echo'</b> | <a href="torrent.php">Search</a> | <a href="addtorrent.php">Add a Torrent</a> | <a href="logout.php">LogOut</a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It does not work, it logs in and displays no username, I have to have it where when logged in you cant see the bottom menu.

Comment: It logs in, and then shows the links non-logged in users should not see.

Comment: @Jon Thank you, that fixed the code, the website is open for signups too.

Comment: No problem, glad I could fix it.  Though, it's not considered good practice to advertise web-sites on here. ^^